# issue implementing relationship in Coredata in Xcode iphone onetoone or manytomany

Tags: xcode, core-data, one-to-many, relationship, one-to-one

I am working on coredata relationships.I am having 2 entities Device and dealers.They have one to many relationship among them.

For device attributes are deviceName,deviceSerial,deviceVersion & for Dealer the attributes are dealeraddress,dealerPhone ,dealerName

I have to created a one to Many relationship from Device to Dealers(each device has multiple dealers) in data model editor

I have set the inverse also .I got a column by the name of ZDeviceDealer in my Dealer table.

I want to fetch the list of dealers from dealers table for a particular device.For this do i have to create a separate column for DeviceSerial in Dealer Table .

How can i make a Predicate and Fetchrequestcontroller for this.

Please correct me where i am wrong.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "create columns" in Core Data, you define attributes and relationships for the
entities. You said that you already defined a one-to-many relationship between *Device* and 
*Dealer", so let us assume that

- `dealers` is the to-many relationship from *Device* to *Dealer*,
- `device` is the inverse to-one relationship from *Dealer* to *Device*.

To fetch all dealers for a particular device, you need the following predicate and 
fetch request:

```
Device *theDevice = ... ;
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Dealer"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"device == %@", theDevice];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

For a fetched results controller, you can start with the sample code from the
[NSFetchedResultsController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and use the above fetch request.